# Doubt on Sakurai's proof of Wigner-Eckart theorem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory

In Sakurai's and Napolitano's book "Modern quantum mechanics" there's a nice proof of the theorem. This can be found also almost identical on Wikipedia's [Wigner–Eckart theorem - Proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%E2%80%93Eckart_theorem#Proof).

The thing that is bugging me about this proof is this part

> We therefore have two sets of linear homogeneous equations
> \begin{align}\sum_c a_{bc} x_c &= 0 &   \sum_c a_{bc} y_c &= 0\end{align}
> one for the Clebsch–Gordan coefficients $x_c$ and one for
> the matrix elements $y_c$. It is not possible to exactly solve for
> $x_c$. We can only say that the ratios are equal, that is
>
> $$\frac{x_c}{x_d} = \frac{y_c}{y_d} \quad\text{or}\quad x_c=ky_c$$

While the rest is clear, I don't get how we conclude the proportionality. In general, this is clearly not true. This is true only if the kernel of the matrix $a_{bc}$ is one-dimensional. So there must be some other property of the coefficients $a_{bc}$ that allows us to conclude that the kernel is one-dimensional, and thus the proportionality of different $x_c$ satisfying the equation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You know that the recurrence relation for the Clebsch's determines them up to normalization, so you know that the kernel of the system of linear equations is indeed one-dimensional.

Comment: perhaps OP is asking why the normalization is the only constraint?

Comment: Doesn't that determine them just up to a phase factor?

Comment: CG coefficints *are* only determined up to phase factors. All the states in a given rep can have a common phase factor.  Ang-mom theory is full of phase choices. The same phase factor ambiguities occur in the states that W-E addresses though, so the phases  don't matter.

Comment: But how can a linear equation determine them up to just a phase? And if the equations determine the solutions up to a phase, that would mean that $|k|=1$ in my question. But that would imply that the proportionality between the CG coefficients and the matrix element, explictly $\left\langle j'||T_k||j\right\rangle/\sqrt{2k+1}$, also has absolute value 1. But is this the case? If this was true then the squared absolute value of the matrix element, which is usually the quantity of interest, would be only determined by the CG coefficient..

Answer (score -1):

I got the same problem these days and I tried to investigate to get a right explanation. It is not a phase problem. You have to focus on the set of linear equations given by the recurrence relations. For fixed j, j' and j" (sorry for bad notation, but I hope you can get it!) you can "easily" see that you always have N Clebsch-Gordan and N-1 equations that can link those coefficients. Thus you can show that the set of linear equations always gives a one dimensional solution... if and only if the rank of the associated matrix is N-1. You can show that when you realize that the associated matrix of the system is in row echelon form.